# JS Variable Not Being Passed Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I've been working on this code for a while. I have a HTML, JS and a Code.js page.

On changing of the value in a Dropdown list on my HTML form, the item in the Dropdown is passed to the Code.js to have the result returned, however, I keep having NULL as my result. -arr is the result.

Another issue, is that I can see in the script logs that getRowData() is being executed twice, not sure why, but this may be overwriting our array.

HTML

JS

```
//$('#searchDropdown').one('change', function(){
//$("#searchDropdown").change(function(){  
//$('#searchDropdown').on('keyup propertychange change', function(){
//$('#searchDropdown').on('input', function(){
//$('#searchDropdown').one('submit', function(){

  $('#searchDropdown').one('change', function(){ 

      var selatr = $('#input1').val();
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(poperr).getRowData(selatr);
      
   });
   
   function poperr(arr){
   alert(arr +" ! ");     
   }
```

Code.GS

```
function getRowData(selatr){
  //Vlookup a GoogleSheet and return the resulting row
  sheet_data.getRange(2,16).setValue(selatr); //set for vlookup
  var x = sheet_data.getRange(3,16).getValues();
  var arr= [];
  arr.push({ 
    id : selatr
    name : sheet_data.getRange(x,2).getValues()
  })
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your vlookup is successfully returning some data and your arr has some value in getRowData function?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've added a Logger.Log()  at the end of getRowData() to see arr. I can see arr is correct

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you have multiple event handlers in your code and your `getRowData` function is being called twice.

Try `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` This stops the rest of the event handlers from being executed.

```
  $('#searchDropdown').one('change', function(e){ 
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     var selatr = $('#input1').val();
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(poperr).getRowData(selatr);
  
  });
```